# Find inclusion graph from ordered set

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let's say I have a set of elements and an order relation (not total) between them.

To keep it simple, let's say its 1D segments with inclusion.

From the raw list of segments, how can I build a graph of direct inclusion (given it's possible from my set):

[image]

from the black segments, how can I rebuild the red graph?

I have a `O(n^3)` solution in C#, which is perfectly ugly, and I wonder if there is anything better [pseudo-code]:

```
interface INode
{
    bool Includes(INode other);
    List<INode> Childs { get; set; }
}

class Graph
{
    public INode Root { get; set; }
}

class GraphBuilder
{
    public static Graph Build(IList<INode> nodes)
    {
        Graph result = new Graph();
        foreach (var segment in nodes) {
            segment.Childs = new List<INode>();
            bool isRoot = true;
            foreach (var segment2 in nodes)
            {
                if (segment2.Includes(segment))
                {
                    isRoot = false;
                }
                if (segment.Includes(segment2))
                {
                    bool isDirectChild = true;

                    foreach (var segment3 in nodes)
                    {
                        if (segment.Includes(segment3) && segment3.Includes(segment2))
                            isDirectChild = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (isDirectChild)
                        segment.Childs.Add(segment2);
                }
            }
            if (isRoot)
            {
                result.Root = segment;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by order relation? Can you please provide a sample input and output?

Comment: @ReazMurshed i provided complete c# code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do a topological sort of the DAG using an efficient algorithm such as [Kahn's algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/) in time `O(V+E)`.

For each element, construct just the arrow from itself to the least (in the topological order) thing it is less than in the original DAG.  Figuring these out also requires time `O(V+E)`.

That's your red graph in time `O(V+E)`.

Note that just reading the DAG takes time `O(V+E)` so this is, up to a constant, the best that you could possibly do.

Comment: Upon revisiting, I realized that there is a problem with this algorithm.  If the red DAG that you are trying to reconstruct is a tree, it will work.  If the red DAG is not a tree, that is there are multiple elements directly above a given one which are not comparable between themselves, then it will not work.  I am leaving it up, though, because if that restriction is OK then it is in fact the most efficient approach.  And if that restriction is not OK then it is probably on the right path to a fairly efficient approach.

Comment: My red graph is a tree. So your solution is perfect! Thanks